# Add another value to nested javascript object?

Tags: javascript, object

I have the following JavaScript object, with a property called rates, which contains another object with the actual rates.  Now I want to add a new rate "CAD":0.972254 to the rates.  How can I add this one value to the list?

```
var Currency = {
  rates: {"USD":1.0,"EUR":1.3497,"GBP":1.60403},
  convert: function(amount, from, to) {
    return (amount * this.rates[from]) / this.rates[to]; 
  }
};
```

Comment: Well... `Currency.rates.CAD = 0.972254` Just like you'd do with any object property access.

Comment: Try Currency.rates.CAD = 0.972254 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it either way

```
Currency['rates']['CAD'] = 0.972254;
```

Or,

```
Currency.rates.CAD = 0.972254
```

**[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gyKAM/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a new property to existing object like:

```
Currency.rates.CAD = 0.972254
```

Answer (score 1):

Currency.rates.CAD = 0.972254;